# Haskell pattern matching not allowed in Elm?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, elm

Following [this Elm tutorial](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/user_input/buttons.html) and I assumed that the function

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
```

is defined in the tutorial as

```
update msg model = 
    case msg of
        Increment  -> model + 1
        Deccrement -> model - 1
        Reset      -> 0
```

I thought I would define it the same way but with syntax I prefer:

```
update Increment model = model + 1
update Decrement model = model - 1
update Reset model     = 0
```

But this doesn't compile, does Elm not support this syntax or did I make a mistake?

Comment: What's the error message you get when you try to compile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the goals of Elm is to use a [consistent style](http://elm-lang.org/docs/style-guide); removing redundant syntax is a conclusion of this. For that reason, you will not find any [`where` clause](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/621) and [function definitions with multiple variants](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/973) are not permitted either.

Comment: As an Erlang dev who moved to Elm I often miss this, but I do like Elm's extremely consistent syntax.